# Can we use must + V1 to show certainty

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

We know that 'must' is used to show obligation, deduction,strong recommendation and also for certainty.

*She must be going to the market*.(certainty/deduction)

*He must study to pass the exam*.(obligation/strong recommendation)

Now my question is can we use must+V1 to show certainty? For example, if I want to say that Ram is very brilliant boy and it is very certain that he reads all the day , can I say

**He must read all the day** (to show certainty) ?

Comment: Yes. She is a very good athlete. She must train a lot.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ok I got it. Now can use must for future certainty? If I want to say that he will obviously go, can I say "he must go" ?

Comment: You can't deduce from something that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Ok. Now if someone says " he must work very hard" , which meaning is to choose? It's obligatory for him to work hard or it's certain that he works hard? I think that depends on the context. Right?

Comment: It's absolutely all about context. It is not always sensible to consider text in isolation. Compare: "He must work very hard because he always looks tired", and "He must work very hard if he is to complete his project by next Tuesday"

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Modals usually have an *epistemic* reading (showing the quality of the speaker's knowledge or certainty) as well as their normal deontic reading, and the epistemic reading of *must* is a conclusion of certainty.

See [*Must*, sense 3 in Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/must#Verb)